# org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Content is not allowed in trailing section

Tags: java

i work with jdom .this error was take place:

```
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 252 of document Articles.xml: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
        at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:530)
        at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:905)
        at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:884)
```

how can solve this error ?

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check that your XML is valid and that there are no non-whitespace characters after the last closing tag of your XML document.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have missed any one of mentioned

```
Not set grails proper Version
Missing application.properties file (with proper grails version)
```